# Is there a way to span long method names across multiple lines?

Tags: c#, syntax

We're using very descriptive test names for work and it's getting very annoying to horizontally scroll across them.  Is there a way to get a method name to span multiple lines in C#?

Something like:

```
MyMethodNameIsReallyLong
    _SoImMakingItSpanMultipleLines
    _SoIDontHaveToHorizontallyScroll
    _AndMyLifeIsMuchEasier()
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Get a wider screen...?  More seriously, how about breaking down the test names into different namespaces, that way it would look more like ThisTestArea.ThisTestFunction.ThisTestName.ThisTestTask?  This would let you span multiple lines.

Comment: erm, aren't you too descriptive? Or maybe the class you are testing is doing too much stuff?

Comment: Code Complete says that when naming routines the emphasis should be on making the name as clear as possible, making it as short or long as you need to make it understandable so there's nothing wrong or evil about long method names per se. However, take into account that the object name also makes up a part of the name to the caller - perhaps the focus should be on reducing the length of the method names rather than figuring out how to split them over multiple lines?

Comment: I think helixed's problem is a pretty common one: How do you clearly identify dozens let alone hundreds of very similar unit tests?

Comment: Use word wrap? (Oprtions->Editor->All Languages)

Comment: -1 for taking the principle of "name your methods descriptively" and turning it into "name your methods\ndescriptively\nway too descriptively."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the short answer is: No.

There is a Description Attribute for TestMethod that "might" be a helpful alternative...

```
[TestMethod, Description("My really long descriptive test name")]
public void Test99()
{
   Assert.Fail();
}
```

Comment: This could help when writing tests.  Additionally, when running tests, the things that matter most are which test failed and why.  In short, the test name can still be terse as you mentioned, and the test's assert messages could be very long and descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

why choose so much lengthy names. length of the first one is enough to understand MyMethodNameIsReallyLong. Function name should be combination of max 4-5 different words which  could be understandable. Such lengthy names should be avoided.

existing examples getElementById/Name - javascript

Comment: Should this be a comment perhaps? I was going to post something similar but does not answer question asked!

Comment: Disagree. He is asking about Test methods. They should be long and descriptive. MakeSureItDoesntBlowUp is not nearly as helpful as 'When_Passing_Both_Null_Values_Make_Sure_It_Exits_Gracefully'

Comment: +1 for Peter. yes it should be. But what i know is that, funtion name should be descriptive from its name , not all lengthy names are descriptive as they stated for test conditions. like MyMethodNameIsReallyLongSoImMakingItSpanMultipleLinesSoIDontHaveToHorizontallyScrollAndMyLifeIsMuchEasier() instead we can use TestMethodBrokenForMakingLifeEasier()

Answer (score 0):

I assume the individual method names are not long enough to require scrolling. If you rearrange the method calls, you'll see more text vertically:

```
MyMethodNameIsReallyLong(
   SoImMakingItSpanMultipleLines(
      SoIDontHaveToHorizontallyScroll()
   )
);
```

Comment: I think you're on the wrong track. OP's one method name is:
MyMethodNameIsReallyLongSoImMakingItSpanMultipleLinesSoIDontHaveToHorizontallyScrollAndMyLifeIsMuchEasier()